DomainEvent published before/after EF SaveChanges
i'm trying to figure out about how to dispatch events in as simple project that uses EF Core.
Base on this, a domain events could be sent before or after saving the changes.
public class OrderingContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    // ...
    public async Task<bool> SaveEntitiesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // Dispatch Domain Events collection.
        // Choices:
        // A) Right BEFORE committing data (EF SaveChanges) into the DB. This makes
        // a single transaction including side effects from the domain event
        // handlers that are using the same DbContext with Scope lifetime
        // B) Right AFTER committing data (EF SaveChanges) into the DB. This makes
        // multiple transactions. You will need to handle eventual consistency and
        // compensatory actions in case of failures.
        await _mediator.DispatchDomainEventsAsync(this);

        // After this line runs, all the changes (from the Command Handler and Domain
        // event handlers) performed through the DbContext will be committed
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

Let's suppose to have a simple CRUD controller that allows to operate with a X entity.
I would like to have 2 different events, Deleted and Created.
I wrote a simple class that has 2 methods
public class XEntity 
{
  private XEntity() {}

  public static XEntity Create() 
  {
    ... 
     var x = new XEntity();
     x.RaiseDomainEvent(new XCreatedDomainEvent(x.Id));
  }

  public void Delete()
  {
    RaiseDomainEvent(new XDeletedDomainEvent(Id));
  }
}

And this is the simple CreatedDomainEventHandler
public class XCreatedDomainEventHandler(IXRepository repo) : INotificationHandler<XCreatedDomainEvent> 
{

  public async Task Handle(XCreatedDomainEvent notification, CancellationToken ctk)
  {
     var x = await repo.GetById(notification.Id);
     .....
  } 
}

Here there is my doubt.
If I put the code that dispatch DomainEvents BEFORE saving changes, of course the handler is not able to retrieve the job already created from repo, cause is it not in DB (as changes not already happen).
But if I put the code that dispatch DomainEvents AFTER saving changes, I'm not able to dispatch the deleted events as the entities were already removed by EF ChangeTraker. This is the code that I use to get the events
private async Task PublishDomainEventsAsync()
{
            var domainEvents = ChangeTracker
                    .Entries<Entity>()
                    .Select(entry => entry.Entity)
                    .SelectMany(entity =>
                    {
                            var domainEvents = entity.GetDomainEvents();
                            entity.ClearDomainEvents();
                            return domainEvents;
                    })
                    .ToList();

     ... dispatch ... 
}


I only see two options: write 2 different method to save entities (DispatchAndSave and SaveAndDispatch), but i don't like this kind of solution, and another one in which I retrieve all entities before savings in order to get the events, save and then dispatch events (but i don't like this one either cause i would like to have same db context for the scope of all events before saving, in order to rollback all if something goes wrong)
Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Before or after simply depends on what you are trying to accomplish with the event.  You could imagine a role for both, eg OnSavingChanges and OnSavedChanges.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft my doubt is caused in my use case by that the Save method is called from XRepository. But the repository doesn't know about which events are raised, cause them are raised inside method of entity (like Create or Delete), so I'm not sure which one method the repo should call
